# Изменение встроенного DRF partial_update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

В django rest framework есть миксин `UpdateModelMixin`. В нём есть action `partial_update`, который в path принимает id, и по этому id обновляет объект. Мне нужно изменить функцию так, чтобы ей не нужен был id, т.к. я хочу получать объект по токену авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно либо указать `lookup_url_kwarg` и / или `lookup_field` в вашем `View`, либо же переопределить метод `get_object` примерно так:

```
...
    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Model, token=token)

        # проверяем permissions объекта
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
...
```

Comment: Забыл упомянуть в вопросе: одной из основных проблем также является отображение в сваггере. Нужно сделать так чтобы сваггер тоже не ожидал получить id, то есть нужно как то модифицировать роут